# Chartist.js and events

Tags: chartist.js

I am trying to add click events on the graphs that I am rendering. From chart.click to chart.on('click', function (e){ }).

What I am trying to do is allow the user to select points on the graph and for me to now what selections the user made. Is that at all possible using chartist.js?

I read through the documentation: [CHARTIST.JS](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html)

My code:

```
if (item.GraphType.Description == "Line") {
    var chart = new Chartist.Line(
        container[0],
        {
            labels: d.Labels,
            series: d.SeriesData
        },
        {
            axisY: {
                offset: 60
            }
        }
    );
    chart.click(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is entirely possible, yes. Chartist renders SVG nodes to the page, so using a library like jQuery you can easily find all nodes that you want and attach events to them. You can be as specific or broad in the nodes you're looking for to only attach events to very specific nodes or elements on the chart.

For completeness sake, here is a short example of how to attach events that log the value of a data point when clicked upon to the console using jQuery:

```
$('.ct-chart-line .ct-point').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("ct:value");
    console.log(val);
});
```

You should, however, make sure that the events attach only when the chart is created or drawn if you want to ensure the data points are on the page, which can be triggered by the "created" or "draw" events:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line(...);
// attach an event handler to the "created" event of the chart:
chart.on("created", function () {
    // attach the necessary events to the nodes:
    $('.ct-chart-line .ct-point').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).attr("ct:value");
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: chart.on("created", function (data) {

                                $('.ct-point').click(function () {
                                    var val = $(this).attr("ct:value");
                                    Handlr.confirm({ message: val });
                                });
                            });

Went about it this way.