# Chartist.js animation end event

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I want to display a block after the chart is ready. I didn't find an "end of animation" event in the [docs](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html). Is there a way to execute some code after all animations are finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2768833/mark) for help. My solve of the problem:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line(...);

var endOfAnimation;
var seq = 0;
var delays = 48;
var durations = 300;

chart.on("draw", function(data) {
    seq++;

    /* Animations */

    /* element.animate({ 
           opacity: {
           begin: seq * delays,
           dur: durations,
           from: 0,
           to: 1
       }); */
}

chart.on("created", function() {
    clearTimeout(endOfAnimation); // prevent function call duplication 

    endOfAnimation = setTimeout( function(){

        /* some code after all animations are finished */ 

    }, (seq + 1) * delays + durations);

    seq = 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the 'created' event handler.

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line(...);
// attach an event handler to the "created" event of the chart:
chart.on("created", function () {
    // call some function
    triggerSomeEvent();
});
```

Src: [Chartist.js and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861541/chartist-js-and-events)

Comment: Thank you for help